# How can i declare a variable outside of a method and then initialize them inside of OnCreate()?

Tags: object, android-intent, null, bundle

My question is the same that is here [.getExtras()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192284/getextras-on-a-null-object-reference/42237978#42237978)

But i dont know how to do that codeMagic says: "You would need to declare them outside of the method and initialize them inside of onCreate(). That or pass the values you need to the necessary functions"

Sorry i'm very new to the programming world.
    `package ejemplo1.listaejemplo;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Lista extends Activity {

    private ListView lista;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lista);

        String elem1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Nombre");
        String elem2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Sexo");

        Espacios[] datos = new Espacios[] {
                new Espacios(elem1, elem2),
                new Espacios("Nombre2", "Sexo2")};

        lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Interesar);

        Adapta adaptador = new Adapta(this, datos);
        lista.setAdapter(adaptador);

    }
    class Adapta extends ArrayAdapter<Espacios> {

        String elem1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Nombre");
        String elem2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Sexo");

        Espacios[] datos = new Espacios[] {
                new Espacios(elem1, elem2),
                new Espacios("Nombre2", "Sexo2")};

        public Adapta(Context context, Espacios[] datos) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, datos);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            View item = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null);

            TextView texto1 = (TextView) item.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            texto1.setText(datos[position].getNombre());

            TextView texto2 = (TextView) item.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
            texto2.setText(datos[position].getSexo());



            return(item);


        }

    }


}
`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.getExtras()' on a null object reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192284/getextras-on-a-null-object-reference)

Comment: Please add a sample of the code you have so far to your question. This allows people to give concrete advice.

Comment: There is my code, i solve the original problem, but i have to duplicate the variable "datos" "elem1" "elem2", now i want to know if exist a way to eliminate the first ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variables `elem1` and `elem2` as class members, just like you did for the `lista` variable. This allows `elem1` and `elem2` to be accesible to all methods in your class. Once that's done, assign your values from `getExtras` to it in the `onCreate()` method.

So for example

```
public class Lista extends Activity {

    private ListView lista;
    //Here we are declaring our elem variables outside the onCreate() method
    //This means that your "Adapta" class can use them
    private String elem1;
    private String elem2;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lista);

        //And here we are assigning them the values from getExtras()
        elem1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Nombre");
        elem2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Sexo");

        Espacios[] datos = new Espacios[] {
            new Espacios(elem1, elem2),
            new Espacios("Nombre2", "Sexo2")
        };

        lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Interesar);

        Adapta adaptador = new Adapta(this, datos);
        lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
    }

    class Adapta extends ArrayAdapter<Espacios> {

        //Notice we have removed elem1 and elem2 from the adapter class
        Espacios[] datos = new Espacios[] {
            new Espacios(elem1, elem2),
            new Espacios("Nombre2", "Sexo2")
        };

        public Adapta(Context context, Espacios[] datos) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, datos);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            View item = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null);

            TextView texto1 = (TextView) item.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            texto1.setText(datos[position].getNombre());

            TextView texto2 = (TextView) item.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
            texto2.setText(datos[position].getSexo());

            return(item);
        }

    }

}
```

I have put a few comments in the example above, i hope this makes things a bit clearer.